# Transparency issue in vim

Tags: macvim, vim

Whenever I source my `.vimrc` file, the the transparent background ends at the last line, or until I create new lines within the current buffer, instead of making the entire window background transparent.  In other words half of my window is transparent and the other half is dark.

The `set transparency=10` option is currently enabled in my `.gvimrc` file at the moment.  Just out of curiosity, why does macvim respond this way?  Is there a fix for this, other than just putting that option in my `.vimrc` file?

Comment: That (crazy) option works like a charm here, did you try with other colorschemes?

Comment: @romainl Yes I've tried it.  The option works fine whenever I toss it in my .vimc, just not when I put it in my .gvimrc and source .vimrc again.  It just gives me a transparent screen that is only as long as the lines in my .vimrc.

Comment: To be honest, it's the first time I hear about that silly option.

Comment: It's only for macvim GUI as state in `:help 'transparency'`

Comment: Have you tried reproducing it on a different terminal application? eg: gnome-terminal